# Deserialize Json into list using Json.net C#

Tags: c#, json, list

I have a JSON data ( http://country.io/names.json ) like :

```
{"BD": "Bangladesh", "BE": "Belgium", "BF": "Burkina Faso", "BG": "Bulgaria", "BA": "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "BB": "Barbados" }
```

I want to list that json like CountryCode-CountryName (BD-Bangladesh) . How do I do that on windows form app. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could deserialise the JSON into a Dictionary instead of a single object. This gives you access to all the codes and names, like so:

```
var json = @"{""BD"": ""Bangladesh"", ""BE"": ""Belgium"", ""BF"": ""Burkina Faso"", ""BG"": ""Bulgaria"", ""BA"": ""Bosnia and Herzegovina"", ""BB"": ""Barbados"" }";

var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

foreach (var item in dict)
{
    var countryCode = item.Key;
    var countryName = item.Value;

    // do whatever you want to do with those two values here
    Console.WriteLine("CountryCode: {0} CountryName: {1}", countryCode, countryName);
}
```

In that code it simply writes it to the screen, but obviously once you have that loop in place you can do whatever you like with the country code and name.